# Usage of "genetically engineered" vs. "genetically modified" animals

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Do the terms:

> genetically engineered

and

> genetically modified

have different meanings?

Is either preferred in the context of working with genetically engineered animals for medical research?

Comment: Preferred in what context?

Comment: An interesting question, but I've never heard anyone say "genetically changed" or "altered" in the same context.

Comment: See this article from [NC State Extension](https://agbiotech.ces.ncsu.edu/q1-what-is-the-difference-between-genetically-modified-organisms-and-genetically-engineered-organisms-we-seem-to-use-the-terms-interchangeably/) on the difference between genetic modification and genetic engineering.

Comment: I have modified the question and tried to answer it in a manner that the educated non-specialist reader could understand.

Comment: @Jim the context is: working with genetically engineered animals for medical research

Comment: I have now edited the question to include the poster's clarification. I need to (genetically?) modify my answer slightly, but I suggest that those who voted the question down and voted to close might now reconsider. Although the context the poster is interested in is scientific, the terms are in general contemporary use, but may be unclear to many. Hence I suggest that it is a useful question.

Comment: While, in general, engineering implies conscious effort toward a goal and modification implies neither the presence nor the absence of such an effort or goal, I would understand them to mean the same thing in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Do they have different meanings?**

> Yes and no.

**Yes:** As @ab2 mentioned, [this article](https://agbiotech.ces.ncsu.edu/q1-what-is-the-difference-between-genetically-modified-organisms-and-genetically-engineered-organisms-we-seem-to-use-the-terms-interchangeably/) states that:

> Genetic modification refers to a range of methods (such as selection, hybridization, and induced mutation) used to alter the genetic composition of domesticated plants and animals to achieve a desired result. Genetic engineering is one type of genetic modification that involves the intentional introduction of a targeted change in a plant, animal, or microbial gene sequence to achieve a specific result.

So in lay language one can say that new strains of plants resulting from breeding are *genetically modified*, but only those that scientists have used DNA technology to alter the genetic material (genome) directly have been *genetically engineered*.

**No:** There is legislation to control the alteration of the genome by direct scientific manipulation in this area both in [Britain](http://www.hse.gov.uk/biosafety/GMO/law.htm) and the [United States](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/restrictions-on-gmos/usa.php). Sample on-line Government documents in the preceding links both refer to this as *Genetic Modification*. So in a legal and, following from this, in a general context the two terms are equivalent and *Genetic Modification* is more common.

As a scientist who was one of the early genetic engineers (of micro-organisms for pure scientific analysis purposes) I can say that [Genetic Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_engineering) was the original scientific ‘buzz’ term, as the linked technical Wikipedia article implies.